# How compare two images using sikuli in robotframework

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

am totaly new to the sikuli with robotframework. I have some want idea of click and action of the window based but i dont have the concept of compare the image using **sikuli** with **robotframework**. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is RaiMan from SikuliX.

I recommend to use 
https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary

Comment: Hi Raiman, thanks for ur reply. But in sikuli, i want to compare two image to check whether that images same or not that code i want..

Comment: What version of SikuliX do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a python script for image comparison, which gets two images to compare the images and write the difference.
 You can use this as robot keyword for image comparison. Challenge is that you have to crop the image from desktop application. you can able to do this using robot framework sikuli library keyword crop region by providing x,y, width and height values

compare images.py

```
# importing the necessary packages
#from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity 
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import time
import logging


def Compare_Image(image1,image2,Original_image_path,Modified_image_path):
    # Reading images
    imageA = cv2.imread(image1)
    imageB = cv2.imread(image2)
    # convert the images to grayscale
    grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #getting the structural similarity between the images
    (score, diff) = structural_similarity(grayA, grayB, full=True)
    diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
    print("SSIM: {}".format(score))
    #Threshold differences
    thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        #Displaying Rectangles on image difference
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(imageA, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(imageB, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    # show the output images
    image1=cv2.imshow("Original", imageA)
    image2=cv2.imshow("Modified", imageB)
    cv2.imwrite(Original_image_path, imageA)
    cv2.imwrite(Modified_image_path, imageB)
    # cv2.imshow("Diff", diff)
    # cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)
    #cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    #Validating and Logging Image Results
    if score==1.0:
        print("Reference and Test images are same")
    else:
        print("Reference and Test images are different")

Sample.robot
```

*** Setting ***

```
Library    compare_Images.py
```

*** Test Cases ***
Check_Image_Compare

```
Compare Image    path_to_image1\\img1.png   path_to_image2\\image2.png 
path_to_saveorginalimage1\\orgimage.png   path_to_savemodifiedimage\\modifiedimage.png    
Log    &lt;img src="path_to_saveorginalimage1\\orgimage.png">    HTML  
Log    &lt;img src="path_to_savemodifiedimage\\modifiedimage.png">    HTML
```

On executing the python script it will give two images (original image- image1 to compare Modified image- image2 to compare) which will be saved in specified location and logged as in robot file above.